# Update UI form from worker thread

Tags: vb.net

I am new to multi-threading in VB.NET and have come across a problem whereby I am wanting to append text to a text box on a form from a service thread running in the background.

The application I am developing is a client/server listener, I have been able to get the client and server PC's to talk with each other (confirmed through MsgBox), however I am now struggling to get the service thread on the server to append the text to the textbox, nothing vissible occurs.

I have a form named testDebug which calls a class (RemoteSupport), this class does all the handshake tasks and updates the textbox with the connection data.

Can anyone identify where I am going wrong and point me in the right direction?

The following is the code I have:
The form has a textbox named txtOutput, the following is from the remoteSupport class

```
Dim outMessage As String = (encoder.GetString(message, 0, bytesRead))
 MsgBox(outMessage, MsgBoxStyle.Information, "MEssage Received")
  If outMessage IsNot Nothing Then
    If testDebug.InvokeRequired Then
        ' have the UI thread call this method for us
        testDebug.Invoke(New UpdateUIDelegate(AddressOf HandleClientComm), New Object() {outMessage})    '
    Else
       testDebug.txtOutput.AppendText(outMessage)
    End If

    'RaiseEvent MessageReceived(outMessage) // a previous attempt to use custom events
 End If
```

I am not sure if the invoke method is the ideal solution or if custom events are, I have spent some time on trying to get custom events to work, but these didnt work either.

```
 // In the RemoteSupport class
 Public Delegate Sub MessageReceivedHandler(ByVal message As String)
 Public Shared Event MessageReceived As MessageReceivedHandler

// Located throughout the RemoteSupport class where debug information is required.
RaiseEvent MessageReceived(outMessage)

// Located in the code-behind of the form
Private Sub Message_Received(ByVal message As String)
testDebugOutput(message) // this is a function I have created 
                         // to append the text to the text box
End Sub
```

The code supplied has been cut down so if there is anything else that you want to see or any questions please let me know.

Thanks for your assistance.

EDIT:  I have uploaded the two VB files (form and class) to my site, I would appreciate it if someone could have a look at it to help me with identifying the problem with the UI not updating.

I have tried a few other things but nothing seems to be updating the UI once the worker thread has started.

Form: mulholland.it/testDebug.vb.txt
Class: mulholland.it/remoteSupport.vb.txt

Thanks for your assistance.

Matt

Comment: I have found a post which might be what I am after, but I dont understand it.  Can someone explain it to me and let me know if this is what I should be doing: "The solution was to pass the parent form to the worker thread by introducing a new property to the class called parentForm. Then when instantiating a new object from the class I only need to pass the mainForm instance to it as a property. Then I can invoke the parent from from within the class directly" (http://www.vbdotnetforums.com/vb-net-general-discussion/28459-update-ui-worker-thread-another-class.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I have a form named testDebug...
>
> ```
> If testDebug.InvokeRequired Then
> ```

This is a classic trap in VB.NET programming.  Set a breakpoint on the If statement.  Notice how it returns False, even though you *know* that the code is running on another thread?

InvokeRequired is an instance property of a Form.  But testDebug is a *class name*, not a reference to an instance of a form of type testDebug.  That this is possible in VB.NET has gotten a lot of VB.NET programmers in deep trouble.  It is an anachronism carried over from VB6.  It completely falls apart and blows up in your face when you do this in a thread.  You'll get a *new* instance of the form, instead of the one that the user is looking at.  One that isn't visible because its `Show()` was never called.  And otherwise dead as a doornail since the thread isn't running a message loop.

I answered this question several times already, with the recommended fix.  I'll just refer you to them rather than rehashing it here:

- [Form is not updating, after custom class event is fired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790574/form-is-not-updating-after-custom-class-event-is-fired/3790667#3790667)
- [Accessing controls between forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643106/accessing-controls-between-forms/3643322#3643322)

Comment: Your links assisted me, after re-thinking the approach I was taking I decided to put the second class within the first class and make use of Me.Control.Invoke, much easier and it works now.  Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Doh, Completely missed that. I've tripped myself up on this very thing before and just looked right past it here. Thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 0):

The Delegate method is likely the way you want to go, but I don't see the declaration of the UpdateUIDelegate anywhere

I believe your code should look something like this (assuming you have a reference to the testdebug form local to your remotesupport class

```
Dim outMessage As String = (encoder.GetString(message, 0, bytesRead))
MsgBox(outMessage, MsgBoxStyle.Information, "MEssage Received")
If outMessage IsNot Nothing Then
    If testDebug.InvokeRequired Then
        ' have the UI thread call this method for us
        testDebug.Invoke(New MessageReceivedHandler(AddressOf Testdebug.Message_Received), New Object() {outMessage})   
    Else
        testDebug.txtOutput.AppendText(outMessage)
    End If
end if
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didnt work, it didnt error but the UI textbox didnt update.

Comment: Hmm, if you step through, does it actually call the delegate or not even get there?

Comment: No it doesnt get to the delegate line.  I have put a message box to test invokerequired and it always returns false.  I have uploaded two files to my webserver which is the class and the form code, if you would like to have a look at it to get a complete picture that would be great.