# Problem accessing a TextBox control from another class/thread in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, multithreading

im trying to access a richtextbox from another class and thread then the ui and i cant seem to get it working. I currently have the sub thats handling the the work inside of a public class and its a sharedsub, im going to be calling it from several different classes and threads but again i cant seem to get it working. the code looks like this.

```
Public Class SharedSubs

Public Shared Sub console(ByVal message As String)
    Dim c As New Form1
    If c.consoleBox.Text.Length > 0 Then
        If c.consoleBox.Text.Substring(c.consoleBox.Text.Length - 3, 3) = "..." Then
            c.consoleBox.AppendText(message)
        ElseIf c.consoleBox.Text.Substring(c.consoleBox.Text.Length - 1, 1) = "." Then
            c.consoleBox.AppendText(ControlChars.NewLine & timeStamp() & message)
        End If
    Else
        c.consoleBox.AppendText(timeStamp() & message)
    End If
End Sub
```

i would be calling sub using `SharedSubs.Console("stringstring")` when this is called from the ui thread it works fine but when its called from anyother thread or class its does nothing, ive confirmed it going thru this code but its not displaying anything in the textbox and its not thru an exception due to delegates either which i figured it would.

Am i doing this completely wrong? some help would be great, thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update UI form from worker thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980130/update-ui-form-from-worker-thread)

Comment: You're doing multi-threading wrong. You aren't supposed to update the UI on a different thread. If you absolutely have to do this, you need to use the [`Invoke` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invoke.aspx) of the `Control` class. Check the documentation for details. There are lots of other, related questions here on Stack Overflow about multi-threading issues. Do a search to find some sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, use an event, then you can have other things attached to your Textupdate... Eg You might want to display it, and log it ... then you just bind the form and the log to the event.

If you really want to call the method on your form, then you'll need to call it on the proper thread. This can be done 2 ways.

In the class where you are creating the Thread you pass a reference to the Form/Control into the constructor (and therefore that is on the same thread at that point). Store the reference in your class. Then create your Thread. (Don't use the shared so that you are referring to the correct instance)

```
Delegate sub ConsoleDelegate(byval message as string)
Public Sub console(ByVal message As String)
```

In your Thread, you then just Invoke the Form.

```
mForm.Invoke(new ConsoleDelegate(addressof DoSomething), new object(){message})
```

OR

From your thread you Call the method on your form, and inside the Method on the form.

```
private Delegate sub ConsoleDelegate(byval message as string)
Public Sub console(ByVal message As String)
  If me.InvokeRequired then
      me.Invoke(new ConsoleDelegate(addressof DoSomething), new object(){message})
      return
  end if 
  'Do the actual work.
end sub
```

Comment: hey if your still watching this, i added your code and it seems to work, but still nothing appears in the textbox and i get no error, i traced it with a break and its running the code but nothing is coming up into the textbox.

Comment: where i have 'Do the actual work here you put in your .. c.consoleBox.AppendText(timeStamp() & message) etc

Answer (score 2):

You can't modify the display of a Winforms UI component from a thread other than the main/UI thread. To update from another thread, check out Control.Invoke's documentation. It has a nice example.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Comment: i understand that, however normally it would give me an error regarding that, this looks like ive done something wrong and its not recognizing it. I believe its more of a cross class issue, or a combo of cross class and cross thread.

Comment: tye: I don't know how a cross-class issue could even exist. That would render OOP pretty useless. :D

Have you tried the Control.Invoke method, yet?

Comment: i have not tried it yet. this seems like something pretty simple, im upset this is giving me such a hard time.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this code on form load:

`Me.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False`

It should fix the problem

Comment: This answer was flagged as "low-quality". It would be helpful to include how this setting might address OP's issue and if there are any detrimental aspects of this setting.

Comment: Better?­­­­­­­­

Comment: Yes. But it doesn't say **how** this fixes problem. Also it sounds like it might be harmful to set this to `False`.

Comment: I answered question, i'm sorry if you don't like it :)

Comment: It wasn't me that didn't like it. It was flagged as low quality by the system.

Comment: Can someone please provide further information about this "illegal cross thread calls"? What's bad about it?

Comment: @PeterCo Threads cannot interact with form, same as backgroundworker.