# vb net threading/class problem

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

Hi guys ive already posted about this and ive used the answers to help me, but im still stuck and i really to get past this and move onto the rest of my program. I'm trying to update a textbox with new text from another class on another thread. I can get this to work no problem on another thread with the same class, and on the same thread in another class. but not on another thread on another class. my code looks like this, when it is run to produces no errors but does not add the test to the text box, what is wierd is i had made some changes to the program to add multiplelines to consolebox.text and then checked console.text from form2 and it produces the values i added but those arent reflected inside in the consolebox for some reason. Someone please help me so i can stop bothering you... lol

```
Public Class Form1
Dim myform2 As New form2
Dim t As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf myform2.display)

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
End Sub

Private Delegate Sub ConsoleDelegate(ByVal message As String)
Public Sub console(ByVal message As String)
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Me.Invoke(New ConsoleDelegate(AddressOf console), New Object() {message})
        Return
    End If
    If Me.consolebox.Text.Length > 0 Then
        If Me.consolebox.Text.Substring(Me.consolebox.Text.Length - 3, 3) = "..." Then
            Me.consolebox.AppendText(message)
        ElseIf Me.consolebox.Text.Substring(Me.consolebox.Text.Length - 1, 1) = "." Then
            Me.consolebox.AppendText(ControlChars.NewLine & timestamp() & message)
        End If
    Else
        Me.consolebox.AppendText(timestamp() & message)
    End If
End Sub

Function timestamp()
    Return "[DATE]"
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    t.Start()
End Sub
```

End Class

Public Class form2

```
Public Sub display()
    Form1.console("hello")
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: in class `form2`, what is `Form1` (class name, instance) and how do you pass it to `form2`?

Comment: well i was assuming since its already been instanciated that the form1.console would work fine, it does goto that code, i traced it. But its almost like its setting up a new textbox that you cant see and putting the info there.

Comment: I don't see how your code can compile. You are referencing a non shared function (`console`) like it was shared (called from the class not an instance of the class)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update UI form from worker thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980130/update-ui-form-from-worker-thread)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass the instance of `Form1` to `form2`:

```
Dim myform2 As New form2(me)
```

and form2:

```
Public class form2
    Dim _form1 As Form1

    Public New(form1 As Form1)
        _form1 = form1
    End Sub

    Public Sub Display()
        _form1.console("hello")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: omg you are my hero!!!! that actually worked, dude ive been working at this for days now.... please vote this guys answer up! thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome, glad it works. But you have to understand class/member visibility (public, private, shared, ...)[*http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/527aztek.aspx*], it's really important and will help working on advanced techniques more effectively